# Mark a location by location google maps v3

Tags: google-maps, location

I want to provide a feature like user will provide a city,state and country. Then my aim is to mark the location provided by the user on the google maps.

My code is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="generator" content="CoffeeCup HTML Editor (www.coffeecup.com)">
    <meta name="dcterms.created" content="Tue, 08 Jan 2013 05:31:17 GMT">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="keywords" content="">
    <title></title>
    <?php
// get and breakdown the results then store them in $var's
$Address = "99999 parkplace, new york, NY";
$urladdress = urlencode($Address);
$Base_url = "http://maps.google.com/maps/geo?q=";
$urlParts = "&output=xml";
$urlrequest = $Base_url . $urladdress . $urlParts;
$xml = simplexml_load_file($urlrequest);
$num = "0";
$value=$xml->Response->Placemark;
    $GeoFindAdd{$num} = $value->address;
    $GeoFindCords{$num} = $value->Point->coordinates;
?>
    <script
src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyDY0kkJiTPVd2U7aTOAwhc9ySH6oHxOIYM&sensor=false">
</script>
    <script>
        var myCenter=new google.maps.LatLng(<?php echo $GeoFindCords{$num}; ?>);

function initialize()
{
var mapProp = {
  center:myCenter,
  zoom:5,
  mapTypeId:google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  };

var map=new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap"),mapProp);

var marker=new google.maps.Marker({
  position:myCenter,
  });

marker.setMap(map);
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
<div id="googleMap" style="width:500px;height:380px;"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

The output of the code is

http://wfs-01.wapka.mobi/300030/300030787_6850a0ae9a.png

Is there something wrong i am doing? Or any other way to mark the location by providing location.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got the answer

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">

<head>

<meta charset="utf-8">

<meta name="generator" content="CoffeeCup HTML Editor (www.coffeecup.com)">

<meta name="dcterms.created" content="Tue, 08 Jan 2013 05:31:17 GMT">
    <meta name="description" content="">

<meta name="keywords" content="">

<title></title>

<script
src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyDY0kkJiTPVd2U7aTOAwhc9ySH6oHxOIYM&sensor=false">
</script>

<script>

var geocoder, map;

function initialize() {

geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(10, 10);

var myOptions = {
    zoom: 0,
    center: latlng,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  }

map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);

codeAddress();

}


function codeAddress() {

var address = "Kottayam, Kerala";

geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {

if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {

map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);

var marker = new google.maps.Marker({

map: map, 

position: results[0].geometry.location
      });

} 
else {

alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
    }
  });
}

</script>

</head>

<body onload="initialize()">
 <div id="map_canvas" style="width: 320px; height: 480px;"></div>

</body>
</html>
```